# Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref)

Tags: hyperref, unicode

I have this warning in a title section:Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}

\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\R}{}{\ensuremath{\symbf{R}}}


\begin{document}
    \R\ is ok   
    \section{But \R\ is not}
\end{document}
```

It is just a warning but I would like to understand.
I found this post: [Package hyperref warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode) in Title Page of Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656197/package-hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string-unicode-in-title-p) but I think it is not exactly the same

Comment: For bookmarks which are generated by commands such as `\section` if `hyperref` is loaded, protected macros cannot be used. But you can use direct Unicode input such as `\section[But  is not]{But \R\ is not}`.

Comment: the next line of the warning tells you what hyperref is doing: ` removing `\R' on input line 214.`. Use `\texorpdfstring` to provide an alternative text for the bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I’ll check that

Comment: @JasperHabicht Where did you find your unicode R (between brackets)? Other letters could interest me

Comment: Those can be found in the [Unicode block "Mathematical Alphanumerical Symbols"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols). In fact, I am not mistaken, `\symbf{R}` more or less replaces the R with the  from this block.

Comment: Thank you @JasperHabicht. \symbf{R} gives me a more rounded R, probably because of the Latin modern font